# Python mechanize script failing to login on specific page

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to use Python to log in to a website before getting the information I want. The below code can log in and it works fine with some webpages:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize

b = mechanize.Browser()
r = b.open("https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/ucp.php?mode=login&redirect=/index.php")
b.select_form(nr=1) 

b.form["username"] = "username"
b.form["password"] = "password"
b.submit()

question_page = "http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/memberlist.php"
into_question_page = urllib2.urlopen(question_page)
read_question_page = into_question_page.read()

print read_question_page
```

But doesn't work with this page:

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/memberlist.php

Is this page special and requires a different tool?